# T-SQL Trigger to subtract previous from current to be inserted in new table

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, triggers

I have a T-SQL table SystemReading which holds meter readings for a water system. After the next reading is taken at a given site I need to subtract the previous reading from the current reading to get the usage between the two reads to be inserted to the SystemUsage table. The first table has ReadingID (identity), SysMeterID (meter site), Reading, ReadingDate. The second table, my usage table, has UsageID (identity), SysMeterID (meter site), Usage, ReadingDate. I need to make sure that only the previous reading of the same SysMeterID as the current is used in the trigger. I was using a CTE before to find this usage but now I need it automatically calculated and inserted to the new Usage table. Any help is appreciated.

Here is my old CTE for a reference:

```
 ;WITH tblDifference as (
    SELECT Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY ReadingID) as RowNumber, Reading, SysMeterID, ReadingDate
    FROM Supplydb.app.SystemReading 
    WHERE SysMeterID = 18

)
SELECT Cur.Reading, Cur.Reading - Prv.Reading as TotalPumped, cur.ReadingDate as Date
FROM tblDifference as Cur
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblDifference Prv
ON Cur.RowNumber = Prv.RowNumber+1
where cur.rownumber = 3
ORDER BY cur.ReadingDate DESC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Hope you can calculate the usage with this insert trigger

```
    CREATE TRIGGER Tgr_AddUsage ON SystemReading  
    AFTER INSERT
    AS 
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        DECLARE @SysMeterID  int

        SELECT @SysMeterID = SysMeterID FROM Inserted

        INSERT INTO SystemUsage (SysMeterID, Usage, ReadingDate)
            SELECT t1.SysMeterID, t1.Reading - t2.Reading as Usage, t1.ReadingDate
              FROM Inserted t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN 
                    (SELECT TOP 2 * FROM SystemReading WHERE SysMeterID = @SysMeterID ORDER BY ReadingID DESC) t2 ON t1.ReadingID <> t2.ReadingID 
    END
    GO
```

Comment: `SELECT @SysMeterID = SysMeterID FROM Inserted` assumes only one row per `insert` statement. That may not be the case.

Comment: I think, he need to calculate usage immediately after adding SystemReading.

Comment: An `insert` statement may add more than one row. The OP's application may or may not insert one row at a time, e.g. a meter reader may return from the field with their Scan-U-Matic and load all the meter readings for the day at once. If your code is based on handling a single row `insert` then it should include code that checks the number of rows in `inserted` and uses `RaIsError` or `Throw` to notify the client if the count isn't `1`.

Comment: THANK YOU so much for the help. Only one row will be added per insert statement.

Answer (score 0):

I'd skip the CTE and employ LAG (partitioned by SysMeterID) and ordered as necessary to to your Current-Previous calculation.

Comment: but the problem with LAG is that it's a query. i need the data pushed into another table. LAG (i believe) would mean that I have to manually start the query every time like the CTE

Comment: LAG itself is a function, not a query. You can use it as part of a query for an INSERT INTO Usage statement. Or an UPDATE statement, I suppose, depending on what your Usage table looks like. If you wish to actually alter/add to your Usage table based on your SystemReading data, you'll need one or the other.

Comment: The question is tagged `sql-server-2008`. `LAG` was introduced in 2012.